# Lifetime of rvalue ref

Tags: c++, c++11, scope, rvalue-reference, rvalue

The code below works fine and as far as I understand every time the function is called, a local variable (i.e. vector) will be created and the ownership will be transferred in a rvalue reference at first call and in a const reference (if I remove it won't even compile) at second call. As a result, the local variables didn't actually die when the function terminated, but when the references in main went out of scope (i.e. in the end of `main()`), ***I think***!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> get_v(void)
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};
    return v;
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int> &&rval_ref = get_v();

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < rval_ref.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << rval_ref[i] << "\n";

    const std::vector<int> &con_ref = get_v();

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < con_ref.size(); ++i)
        std::cout << con_ref[i] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ g++ -std=c++0x -Wall px.cpp
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ ./a.out
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

But I thought local variables die when they got out of scope, except if a `static` keyword precedes them, or they have been dynamically allocated, or even get copied. In this case, the vector is not copied. Maybe my C background keeps me back from understand the concept here. Can you help me please?

As a sidenote, the first case lets you modify the vector, while the second obviously won't. Guess the first is a C++11 feature, while the second is the traditional one.

---

I just made an example with a custom class and the ***copy constructor won't be called***, but it will work as the example above!

Comment: `get_v` returns by _value_ not by _reference_.

Comment: So, the copy constructor will be called @CaptainObvlious? I was told by a friend it would not!

Comment: The copy may be elided  it might not be. Depends on optimizations. Either way you are still returning by value so a unique instance of the vector belonging to the caller will created.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious still this is not obvious for me, sorry! Check my edit too. I can't understand how this happens.

Comment: You return a copy which becomes a *temporary* (unnamed) object. Your `const&` then binds to the unnamed temporary giving it a name (thus extending its life).

Comment: Oh @Galik such a nice explanation. Is that what David talks about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write `std::vector<int> &&rval_ref = get_v();` these are the conceptual steps when `return v;` is reached

1. A temporary object, called the *return value* is created. This object is initialized as if by `std::vector<int> x{v};`. It "lives" in `main` and would naturally "go out of scope" when this statement in `main` has finished.
2. `v` is destroyed
3. The reference `rval_ref` is bound to that temporary object. Binding a reference to a temporary object causes the object to have its lifetime extended to match the reference's lifetime.

The name "temporary object" is a bit of a misnomer since the object actually may last quite a long time, but nevertheless that is the official name.  "Unnamed object" is another possible description.

Your references do not refer to `v`, they refer to a copy of it (since your function returns by value). So even though `v` is destroyed, the copy is not destroyed.

Your test code did not show a copy-constructor call (step 1 above) because of *copy elision*.  Copy elision means that the compiler may choose to use the same memory space for `v` as it would have used for the *return value*; and omit the destructor for `v` and the copy-constructor for the return value (even if those functions had side-effects).

Answer (score 3):

Your `get_v` function returns a value, so it doesn't matter that `v` goes out of scope, since you return its *value*.

It's no different from:

```
int a()
{
    int j = 3;
    return j; // returns the *value* of j
}
```

The C++ standard permits the compiler to elide the copy constructor by somehow forwarding `v` to the caller. The C++ standard also requires the lifetime of a temporary to be extended if a reference is bound to it.

Comment: Oh a forwarding it's the key here. Can you expand a little bit on this please (I would really appreciate to here some simple words from you) or provide an explanatory link?

Comment: See [return value optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) and [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks David. From the example there, I understand that forwarding has to do with RVO (is it the same thing? I guess not...). So, in that case, the compiler is smart enough to not destroy the local variable, but "rename" it, by giving it the name of the variable in `main()`? I am not sure why you linked me to the copy ε.

Comment: @gsamaras Right. It seems you got it. Yeah, the link to RVO was wrong.

Comment: Great David, thanks. Still it's unclear to me why you linked me to the copy ε link. Is it a more general concept that is a superset of RVO?

Comment: @gsamaras *Copy elision* is what the standard uses when referring to elided copies and moves, RVO is an informal name for one kind of copy elision. Copy elision can also occur when throwing and catching, and when copying unbound temporaries (which often occurs right after RVO).